# Need to push a parameter in a function to an array as an object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having issues with this function I'm writing.

```
function addToCart(item) {
  let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  cart.push({ item: price });
  console.log(`${item} has been added to your cart.`);
  return cart;
};
```

When I look at what's stored in my cart array, it has "item: 32" for example, rather than the item name that's passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
cart.push({ item: price });
```

to

```
var temp = {};
temp[item] = price;
cart.push(temp);
```

This create a new property on the temp object after object is declared.

---

If you can use **ES6** then just do

```
cart.push({ [item]: price })
```

This evaluates the variable `item` at the time of object creation. In ES5, you cannot use a variable as a property name inside an object literal.